How to solve for \$v_0\$ in this circuit using superposition, and node-current method?
I'm probably missing something trivial but I'm banging my head over this problem for a few hours already.

I think what throws me off is the dependent current source behavior when we are shorting E2, from my understanding a short circuit draws "infinite" current, but since you have the dependent current source afterward it should be just \$-I_1\$, so which one takes priority? also does a dependant current source "consume" voltage? or is it fair to assume that the voltage before and after it are equal?
for example, in the following two circuits, I don't know how to analyze them because of what I explained



I applied the principle of superposition of effects to the analysis of the given network. After solving some algebraic equations, we move forward at full speed....hoping not to have made any mistakes....


Confirmed with simulation circuit.

I'm sorry but I have a question about sub-circuit 1: (also how are you generating these images? They look clean and informative)
Why is I1_1 equal to what you wrote and not with a coefficient of (beta+1) for (R1I1_1)? From my understanding, it should be the voltage at the top node below the voltage at the bottom node (which is ground) so you pass through the resistor with its voltage being V1, then through the 10v battery, and then through the dependent source which subtracts another 3V1 os in total 10-4*V1_1

The circuit drawing provided by you, after being selected and copied (by pressing the STAMP key) was modified using Windows PAINT and pasted into the worksheet.

I1 is present on the left and right of the written relation. It is an equation in the unknown I1 which, when solved, gives the written function.

All of this was done in a MAthcad 15 worksheet (which is no longer available).
